# Visual studio online Rest Api query- Get results sorted by a field

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I am querying visual studio online API to get a list of work items. The result that I get is by default sorted based on the work item ID. I am trying to get the result sorted by TargetedDate field.

Any idea on how to specify the sort column in the rest query?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

I think you might have to build a WIQL query using an `ID in (1,2,3)` filter and execute it.

That way you can specify sorting as `ORDER BY TargetDate`.

For example:

```
POST
https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "query": "Select ID From WorkItems Where ID in (1,2,3) ORDER BY TargetDate ASC"
}
```

More info on the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and [WIQL syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops) is available on MSDN Docs.

---

Or....

Just sort it client-side ;)

Comment: Thanks, i am using a saved query. Is there a way to achieve it when I use saved query. Sure I can do the client side sorting.

Comment: If it is a saved query, you should save the query with the sorting in Visual Studio/ VSTS Web. If you want a different sort for your REST call and your usual view, you will need to sort client side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the sort column for the query before use it.

From REST API, [update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/queries#Updateaquery) it use the WIQL query as DaveShaw mentioned.

From VSO Web Portal, update the settings for the query from "Column options\Sort Columns", add "Target Date" to "Selected Columns" and select the sort type you want.
[image]

Comment: The data returned by the WIQL REST API does not seem to honor the sort order configured in the query